# Reference request: product in $\mathbb{C}_q[X] \otimes \mathbb{C}_q[Y]$.

Tags: quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

Let $a \otimes b, a'\otimes b' \in \mathbb{C}_q[X] \otimes \mathbb{C}_q[Y]$, where $X, Y$ are two algebraic varieties. Suppose that algebraic group $T$ acts on $X, Y$. Then there are coactions $\delta: \mathbb{C}_q[Y] \to \mathbb{C}_q[T] \otimes \mathbb{C}_q[Y]$, $\delta: \mathbb{C}_q[X] \to \mathbb{C}_q[T] \otimes \mathbb{C}_q[X]$. There is a formula:
\begin{align}
(a \otimes b) (a'\otimes b') = a \cdot b'_{(-1)}(a') \otimes b'_{(0)} b,
\end{align}
where $b'_{(-1)} \otimes b'_{(0)} = \delta(b')$ (here we use the Sweedler notation). Are there some reference about this formula? Thank you very much.

Edit: the formula should be
\begin{align}
(a \otimes b) (a'\otimes b') = a (b_{(-1)}.a') \otimes b_{(0)} b,
\end{align}
$\delta(b) = b_{(-1)} \otimes b_{(0)} \in \mathbb{C}_q[T] \otimes \mathbb{C}_q[Y]$. We also require that $\mathbb{C}_q[T]$ acts on $\mathbb{C}_q[X]$.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but what is ${\mathbb C}_q[X]$?

Comment: @Hanno, thank you for your interest. $\mathbb{C}_q[X]$ is the quantized coordinate ring of $X$. There is [a paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9903091) about $\mathbb{C}_q[X]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $\delta$ gives what is called a *Yetter--Drinfeld*-module. The quantized coordinate rings are algebra objects within this category, and the tensor product is the braided tensor product in the category of Yetter--Drinfeld modules over $\mathbb{C}_q[T]$. This means that the product structure is defined as follows:
$$m_{A\otimes B}:=(m_A\otimes m_B)(Id_A\otimes \Psi_{A,B}\otimes Id_B)$$
Here, both $A,B$ are object in this category of Yetter--Drinfeld modules, and $\Psi$ is the braiding in the category, while $m_A$ denotes multiplication on $A$.

The Yetter--Drinfeld structure on the quantum coordinate rings is probably induced by the dual quasitriangular structure on $\mathbb{C}_q[T]$.

As this is a reference request: The fact that the category of Yetter--Drinfeld modules is braided is standard. It can be found in textbooks such as Majid's *Foundations of Quantum Group Theory*.
I am not sure where to find the other details.